# Estimated random effects correlation of 1 when fitting a random intercept model using lme

Tags: r, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit the linear random effects model:

$y_{ijk}=\theta_{ij}+\epsilon_{ijk},$

where $\theta_{ij}$ is a random effect. I assume the random effects and error distributions are normal. Furthermore, I assume that the index $i$ takes only two values $i=1,2$, and that the random effects for $i=1,2$ are correlated for a fixed $j$, but independent over values of $j$. Finally, I assume that the errors are uncorrelated with fixed variance depending only on the index $i$.

Using the `nlme` library, I fit the model as

```
fm <- lme(fixed = y ~ ii - 1, data = mydata, random=list(jj=pdsymm(~ii-1)),weights=varIdent(form=~1|ii))
```

where `ii` represents the variable that is indexed by $i$ and `jj` represents the variable that is indexed by $j$.

Running a simulation of the model and fitting it using the above data seems to reproduce the parameters used in the simulation, however, for a real data set that I am fitting, I obtain a random effects correlation between $i=1$ and $i=2$ of $\rho=1$. Separate estimates of $\theta_{ij}$ using a fixed effects model, followed by calculation of the correlation between $i=1,2$ results in an estimated correlation of $\rho=.7$.

My questions are as follows:

1) Does the `lme` statement seem to be correctly formulated?

2) What are some possible reasons that I may be obtaining a random effects correlation of $\rho=1$, and how might I go about determining the cause? The data does display characteristics not captured by the model (such as heterogeneity of variance over the index $j$, and an outlier.)

Please let me know if I should include any further explanation.

Thanks!

Clark